# ssl certificate- get private key from csr

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to export private key from **`CERTIFICATE SIGNING REQUEST`**?

I have a `CSR` file and some `CRT` files. Now I have to install this **certificate**. How do I do it or do I need some other files in order to install this **certificate**?

Comment: No, the CSR contains only the public key. And it is not clear from your question where you want to install the certificate. And probably this is not a programming question so it does not belong to stackoverflow (server questions at serverfault).

Comment: As Steffen said, a CSR does *not* contain your private key. Voting to close as a typo or unable to reproduce.

Comment: Any chance it can be exported from CRT file? They gave 3 crt files and a csr file and asked me to install it to a domain. I have cpanel access. So is it not possible?

Comment: @user3354638 Neither a CSR nor a certificate file contains a private key. You must have already had a private key when you generated the CSR. That's the one you need. If you've lost it, you will have to re-key, generate a new CSR, and get it signed by the CA.

Answer (score 19):

No you cannot export the private key from CSR because the CSR does not contain any private key.

You need another file that has a private key and if you have that you won't need the CSR to extract the private key.

Answer (score 7):

You create CSR from a private key not other way around.

In general the process goes like

1. You create private key
2. You create CSR  Hand CSR to Certificate Authority aka CA
3. CA will give you a Certificate
4. you are good to go with you private key and with certificate depending upon client e.g. PHP Curl is fine with it
5. You may also combine your private key and Certificate using PKCS12 format depending upon your client requirements.

Comment: Can I generate a new pvt key with existing CSR? The one I create doesn't have a passphrase and the team who updates the cert doesn't accept the pvt key without passphrase.

Comment: @Himanshu with passphrase means that your key is also encrypted with "passphrase" so you can encrypt your existing private key. So there is no reason to create a new key in such case. Anyway, no matter what, you can't get the private key from CSR. In case it does, It kills the idea of private key being private.

Answer (score 5):

First comes the private key generated by you.  openssl is a great utility for this.

Then the public key can be generated from the private key, or a Certificate Signing Request file can be generated which contains the public key in addition to extra information about your company and your site.

That CSR is pasted (using the Godaddy or Digicert methods) into a certificate request form on their respective sites.  There is a verification process which may happen automatically or by email.

Then they'll generate a cert which you can use -- the public key is part of the cert.

So notice that you started off with a generated public private key pair, and ended with a cert private key pair.

If you're talking about a 'client' (general rule, this process can go back and forth), in general it will use just the cert, which is sent from the server during TLS (ahem, was SSL) negotiations.  Or a utility program will use a cert when talking to a 'server' that is paired with it.  The server is the one that will decrypt with the private key what was encrypted using the public key embedded in the cert.

So if all you have is a cert, in general you are talking about a client that knows which server it is going to go to.

But usually you are talking about a server, in which case the private key is probably already installed, and all you are doing is updating the cert.  So if we are talking about a webserver, there are going to be configuration files which will point you to where the 'old' cert is that you are replacing.  You'll also see where the key is, but that wouldn't need to be replaced unless you started the process by generating a new key.  If so, then you'd also replace the old key with the new key.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up in the same situation when I was given a new certificate from a third party for an existing CSR.

The initial CSR was complete and certificate was installed in Windows environment. When I tried to import the new certificate it was imported without its private key. This link was very helpful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/assign-certificate-private-key

Basically when creating a CSR (from IIS etc.) Windows stores the private key internally. When importing the certificate to the same machine, Windows automatically signs it with the private key.

When you import it for a second time. You have to use the command:

```
certutil -repairstore my "SerialNumber"
```

Where Serial number is the imported certificate's serial number

Comment: Many thanks for your effective solution, it's working for me. @emregon